# Working around the Network Loopback Isolation of UWP Apps

Tags: networking, windows-10, udp, loopback, uwp

I've been hitting a blockage trying to get my UWP App to receive data from a local UDP port in the following scenario:

- Windows 10 | Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- UWP target and minimum Version 10.0.16299
- Declared capabilities :

  - Internet (Client & Server)
  - Internet (Client)
- UdpClient listening on 127.0.0.1:1234
- Tested on two different systems in different networks with the same resulting behaviour

---

I am aware of the `CheckNetIsolation` tool and already tried the following steps multiple times:

- Ensuring that the App is registered while running with `CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -s`
- Clearing all exemptions with `CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -c` and manually adding the App with `CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -a -n=*Package Family Name*`
- Running the App while all restrictions are cleared with `CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -c`

I am running my App from Visual Studio, `awaiting for UdpClient.ReceiveAsync()` to return something in a while loop.

My code works fine when i use it from a .Net Framework 4.7.2 Console App, so i can exclude any errors interfering on that end.

---

The **only** thing that lets me receive data in my UWP App is running `CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -is -n=*Package Family Name*`. As soon as i stop it from running, my UDP client stops receiving aata.

---

Sadly, the solution i found and other tools that redirect communication so that they appear to be sent by another source are not possible due to different contraints.